# gcc dynamic linking dependency missing library?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

main.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
int output() {
    printf("thread\n");
}
int keke();
int main()
{
    //keke();
    std::thread th(output);
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

keke.cc

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int keke()
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    return pthread_attr_init(&attr);
}
```

Makefile

```
haha: libkeke.so
    g++ -std=c++11 -o haha main.cc -L. -lkeke -pthread 
libkeke.so: keke.cc
    g++ -o libkeke.so -fPIC -shared keke.cc -pthread
clean:
    rm libkeke.so haha
```

`make` and the result haha will not load pthread.so,

```
(link)$ ldd haha
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff65972000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9dee04a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9dede34000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9deda6f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9ded769000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9dee34e000)
```

`ldd` shows that the executable does not depends on pthread library and it will crash. However if uncomment the call to `keke` from `main.cc`, the program works well.

In conclusion, gcc would not write the dependency library(`pthread`) to dynamic section if the previous shared library(`libkeke.so`) already depend on it. However, if the executable does not refer any symbol in the specific library(does not call keke), ld would not write the library(`libkeke.so`) to dynamic section either. In consequence, `ld.so` would not load the dependency library(`pthread`) and the executable(`haha`) would crash.

The problem is why not gcc write the depend in the dynamic section no matter whether it is already included in previous depends just like msvc does? Is there any drawback to do this?

Comment: `libpthread` [shows up on my computer](http://pastebin.com/8pbpJxxV) with or without the call to `keke();` and the program does not crash; this is on Ubuntu 14.04 and GCC 4.9.2

Comment: @m.s. so 4.9.2 changed the algorithm? I am using gcc4.8.4 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to coincide with your description. First of all there's no call of `keke` in `main.cc`. In addition `main.cc` probably uses `libpthread` anyway as it creates a thread. I too fail to reproduce the claimed behaviour, I use gcc 4.7.2-5 on Debian.

Comment: I haved test it with gcc4.9.2, everything works fine. I guess only version 4.8.4 has this problem.